# redirect a parked domain page to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce, dns

I have a parked domain like example.org and a main domain like example.ir
I want when user is in parked domain and goes to example.org/checkout redirect to example.ir/checkout
only for this page and only when user is in parked domain.
I use this code but doesn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://example.org/checkout(.*) https://example.ir/checkout$1
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$
RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ http://example.ir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Makes sense for checking domain beforehand.

Comment: its work fine. but product main in .org/checkout  and not add to .ir/checkout page.

Comment: can i redirect all pages of main domain to parked domain?

Comment: @Muhama Yes you can Redirect all pages from your main domain to the parked one. You will need to use the following Rule for that :

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://parked domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]`

Answer (score 1):

In  `mod_alias`   `RedirectMatch` you should start with slash in old URI like this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old(.*) https://example.com/new$1
```

That is in general and if the path from main domain to others so, in your case you should use `mod_rewrite` like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^checkout(.*)$ https://%1example.ir/checkout$1 [R=301,L]
```

By the rules above , you would check first is the request contains `example.org` then if a URI start with `checkout` and then redirect it to main domain.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule in your parked domain server,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.ir/$1 [R=302]
```

Comment: i have only one host in my main domain and when i insert above code in htaccess: when goes to /chekout   redirect to main .ir URL

Comment: So you might have to insert the above into virtual host of org domain inside your htaccess I think.

Comment: where is virtual host?

Comment: can i redirect all pages of main domain to parked domain?